# Modify Confluence's body element

Tags: javascript, jquery, confluence

Why won't this work in Confluence:

```
AJS.$("body").attr("onload", AJS.$("body").attr("onload") + " myFunction()");
```

I want to append my own function to the onload attribute of the body element but when I add this code to the Main Layout, Confluence just ignores it. When I try this code using the Chrome debugger, it works just fine.

Edit: I guess I should be a little more clear: The above code seems to work when the Confluence page is loaded the first time. But when the page enters into edit mode, the custom script isn't executed.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, wait until the whole page has loaded. In some cases, in particular when plugins are manipulating the DOM, you may have to put in a delay of a second or two before your script runs.

Using JQuery:

```
{html}   
<script type="text/javascript"> 
AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    AJS.$("#comments-section").hide();
});   
</script>
{html}
```

Using JavaScript:

```
{html}
<script type="text/javascript">
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            if (oldonload) {
                oldonload();
            }
            func();
        }
    }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
   var ele = document.getElementById("comments-section");   
   ele.style.display = "none";;
}) 
</script>

{html}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may depend on many things. For example whether myFunction is already available at the moment when the onload handler wants to execute it.

But why don't you use a more standard way of achieving this:

```
AJS.$(document).ready(myFunction);
```

or if you really want to react on the load event

```
AJS.$(document).load(myFunction);
```

Comment: the one with load does indeed not work ... funny ... do you really need to load all resources, i.e. including images and such before myFunction triggrs ?

Comment: In my case, I need myFunction to read the URL, determine if it matches a particular string, and then hide a set of elements.
Thanks for the suggestion but those still don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Base on a discussion with an Atlassian developer, "The proper way to execute a function when the page is loaded is: AJS.$(function($){ ... your code ... });"

This does work for the initial page load but when the page goes into edit mode, this doesn't get executed. Several console.log outputs confirm this.